# Best Practices on using C# Intellisense Comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, comments, intellisense

We have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that contains several C# projects in accordance with Jeffery Palermo's Onion Architecture pattern (http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).  We want to add the Visual Studio Intellisense Comments using the triple slashes, but we want to see if anyone knows of best practices on how far to take this.  Do we start all the way down in the Model in the Core project, and work up through Infrastructure and into the DataAccess Services and Repositories, and into the User Interface?  Or is it better to use these comments in a more limited fashion, and if so what are the important objects to apply the Intellisense Comments to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add them to any methods exposed in public APIs, that way you can give the caller all the information they need when working with a foreign interface. For example, which exceptions the method may throw and other remarks.

It's still beneficial to add these kinds of comments to private methods, I do it anyway to be consistent. It also helps if you plan on generating documentation from the comments.

Answer (score 4):

While, technically, there is such a thing as too much documentation, 99.99999% of the time this exception doesn't apply.

Document everything as much as you can.  Formal, informal, stream of thought..every scrap of comments will help some poor soul who inherits your code or has to interface with it.

(It's like the old rule "The error may be in the Compiler and not your code. Compilers have errors too.  This is not one of those times.")

Do we start all the way down in the Model in the Core project, and work up through Infrastructure and into the DataAccess Services and Repositories, and into the User Interface? **Yes**

Or is it better to use these comments in a more limited fashion, and if so what are the important objects to apply the Intellisense Comments to?  **If you want to.  Apply them to any function you write, and not what VS autogenerates**

I've seen limited "intellisense" comments..but extensive in-code comments that follow.  So long as the "content" is there, life will be good.  I generally include a brief blurb about each function in the intellisense comments, but put the majority of "here's why i did this" in the function and dead-tree documents.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with fletcher.  Start with public facing classes and methods and then work your way down into private code.  If you were starting from scratch I would highly recommend adding the XML comments to all code for your own convenience, but in this case starting with public methods and then updating other classes whenever you go in to update them is a good solution.